# How can I test a method being called once

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mocking, laravel-6, mockery

Basically I want to test that when I call a method 2 times another method is called once but I get the following Exception:

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Received
>   Mockery_0_App_Repository_DimensionRepository::getThinClientDimension(),
>   but no expectations were specified

My test is as follows

```
class HostRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
/**
 * @var HostRepository
 */
private $hostRepository;

/**
 * @var Dimension
 */
private $dimension;

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->dimension = new Dimension();
    $mockDimensionRepository = Mockery::mock(DimensionRepository::class);
    $mockDimensionRepository->shouldReceive('getDimensionByName')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($this->dimension);
    $this->hostRepository = new HostRepository($mockDimensionRepository);
}

/**
 * Test lazy loading dimension retrieval
 */
public function testGetThinClientDimension()
{
    $this->hostRepository->getEnvironmentsHostList([]);
    $this->hostRepository->getEnvironmentsHostList([]);
}
}
```

HostRepository:

```
[...]
/**
 * @param $configurationIds
 * @return Host[]|Collection
 */
public function getEnvironmentsHostList($configurationIds)
{
    //dd('test'); If I uncomment this it will be executed in the test
    $hostDimension = $this->dimensionRepository->getThinClientDimension();
    dd($hostDimension); // This is not executed if the test is ran
    //Returns an entity through Eloquent ORM
    [...]
}
```

DimensionRepositoy:

```
class DimensionRepository
{
private $thinClientDimension;

const THINCLIENT = 'ThinclientId';

[...]

public function getDimensionByName($name)
{
    return Dimension::where(['Name' => $name])->firstOrFail();
}

/**
 * Lazy load Thinclient dimension
 * @return Dimension
 */
public function getThinClientDimension()
{
    dd('test'); // This part is not executed when running the test which I find weird
    if ($this->thinClientDimension === NULL) {
        $this->thinClientDimension
            = $this->getDimensionByName(self::THINCLIENT);
    }
    return $this->thinClientDimension;
}
[...]
```

Update:

It seems that when I call `$this->dimensionRepository->getThinClientDimension()` (in `getEnvironmentsHostList`) the exception is thrown.

Seems I have to mock this as well (`getThinClientDimension`) which would make my test useless because as you can see it delegates the call to the mocked method `getDimensionByName`...

Comment: What does `$this->getDimensionByName(` do? Is there any call there that can be mocked to check if it is called multiple times?

Comment: `getEnvironmentsHostList` calls `getThinClientDimension` which calls `getDimensionByName` (which I mocked or tried to mock)

Comment: But `getThinClientDimension` is a function on you `HostRepository`?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to separate them in the question, the method `getThinClientDimension ` is in the `DimensionRepositoy`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the fix was to use `makePartial()` when mocking the object

```
public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->dimension = self::getDimension();
    $this->mockDimensionRepository = $this->mock(DimensionRepository::class)->makePartial();
    $this->hostRepository = new HostRepository($this->mockDimensionRepository);
}
```

LegacyMockInterface

```
/**
 * Set mock to defer unexpected methods to its parent if possible
 *
 * @return Mock
 */
public function makePartial();
```

Seems that this modifier tells Mockery it can call other methods that are not mocked (which should be by default in my opinion)